# .fadeto() not working for dynamic class in jquery

Tags: jquery

My Code is like this.

```
<script>
var i=0;
$(window).load(function() {
  $(function() {
   setInterval(update, 1000);
  });
  function update() {
  i++;
  setTimeout(function(){$("#container").after($('<div>',{text:'Hello',class:'test'+i}))},100);
   $("#container .test"+i).delay(500).fadeTo('slow',0);
  }
});
</script>
```

.after() seems working.
But .fadeto() doesn's work.

**I know there are utilities for dynamic classes like .on() and .live() .
But I dont know how can .fadeTo be working for dynamic classes.**

Any ideas?

Comment: You're delaying an animation inside a timeout inside an interval? Makes perfect sense.

Comment: And you're not setting the class either, `class` is a reserved keyword, and you have to quote it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. So you mean I have to write <div "class"="test1"/><div "class"="test2"/><div "class"="test3"/>... on html??

Comment: No, you have to write `$('<div />',{text:'Hello', 'class':'test'+i})` when you create elements.

Comment: Now I tried it. But it didnt solve the probllem.

Comment: It displayes "<div class='test1'>Hello</div> <div class='test2'>Hello</div> ..." but .fadeto is not working

Comment: @user2488882 fadeTo won't work if the DOM wasn't updated when it was called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
<script>
var i=0;
$(window).load(function() {
  $(function() {
   setInterval(update, 1000);
  });
});

  function update() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      // notice the change of class naming convention i.e. .test.t1, .test.t2
      $("#container").after($('<div>',{text:'Hello',class:'test t'+ ++i}))},100);
    }
  }

    // will work with all of the .test class objects within #container
    $("#container .test").on('load',function() {
      $(this).delay(500).fadeTo('slow',0);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I noticed syntax error in your code and modified. But it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @user2488882 i'm sorry my jQuery is rusty (haven't practiced lately) and I couldn't test the code because I don't understand what you want it to do. But the point was to show you a way of using the '.on' with dynamic objects.

Comment: Yes. Your advice nealy solved the problem.　But '.on' can't be used with 'load'. So now I wanna know the substitution for .on(load)

Comment: It can; See: `.load()` http://api.jquery.com/load-event/. This method is a shortcut for `.on('load', handler)`.